# Loop thought items and store the result by comparing the words letter by letter

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have 2 D arrays and want to compare each word from array a to each word from array b, letter by letter.

Let's say

```js
a = [['letter'], ['yellow'], ['planet'], ['blue'], ['sun']]
b = [['letter'], ['yellow'], ['planet'], ['blur'], ['son']]

console.log(this.a[0][0]); // first word first letter
console.log(this.b[0][0]); // first word first letter


for (let i = 0; i < this.b.length; i++) { // 5 words
  for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) { // 6 letter max
    if (this.a[i][j] === this.b[i][j]) {
     console.log('ok', i, j, this.a[i][j], this.b[i][j]);

    } else {
     console.log('hmm');
    }
  }
}
```

It compares right, but it alerts ok each time, when the letter from a = letter from b, and I would like to alert when word from a = word from b, so maximum it alerts 5 times. Can't understand what I am doing wrong and how to fix it, could you please help me?...

Comment: [letter] isnt valid. Why do you need a 2D array for this? Why j<6?

Comment: You probably meant to put the words in a string otherwise the syntax isn't valid. A string itself can be considered as an array of characters. `a = [['letter'], ['yellow'], ['planet'], ['blue'], ['sun']];` becomes a 3D array and would require three nested for loops.

Comment: @raven "abc"==="abc" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable to control this:

```js
a = ['letter', 'yellow', 'planet', 'blue', 'sun'];
b = ['letter', 'yellow', 'planet', 'blur', 'son'];

for (let i = 0; i < this.b.length; i++) { // 5 words
  let equals = true;
  for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) { // 6 letter max
    if (this.a[i][j] === this.b[i][j]) {
     // alert ('ok');

    } else {
     // alert ('hmm');
     equals = false;
     break;
    }
  }
  alert(a[i] + ' equals: ' + equals);
}
```

Comment: Yes, the best would use `length`, but I just answered the question, how to eliminate the alerts for each letter comparing

Comment: pontugal add "test" and "test" and it will break

Answer (score 0):

You can just move the condition to the outer loop and count how many letters were matched.

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.b.length; i++) { // 5 words
    let matchedLetters = 0;

    for (let j = 0; j < this.b[i].length; j++) { // 6 letter max
        if (this.a[i][j] === this.b[i][j]) {
            matchedLetters++;
        }
    }

    if (matchedLetters === this.a.length) {
        alert('ok');
    } else {
        alert('hmm');
    }
}
```

Be careful with the index in the loop condition. I replaced `j < 6` with `j < this.b[i].length` (which is not very clean) because just comparing `j < 6` can give you an index error.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like the following. I also adapted the code to being able to handle words of arbitrary length. I assume that you have a particular reason for comparing the words character-wise, though (since you may as well just use `a[i] === b[i]`).

```js
a = ['letter', 'yellow', 'planet', 'blue', 'sun'];
b = ['letter', 'yellow', 'planet', 'blue', 'sun'];

for (let i = 0; i < this.b.length; i++) { // 5 words
  let j = 0;
  // longest word (in case it differs)
  const max = this.a[i].length > this.b[i].length 
    ? this.a[i].length 
    : this.b[i].length;
  
  // increment j as long as a[i][j] and b[i][j] are equal
  for (; this.a[i][j] === this.b[i][j] && j < max; j++);

  if (j === max) {
    console.log('ok');
  } else {
    console.log('hmmm');
  }
}
```